# Is there an efficient function to calculate a product?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for a `numpy` function (or a function from any other package) that would efficiently evaluate

[image]

with *f* being a vector-valued function of a vector-valued input *x*. The product is taken to be a simple component-wise multiplication.

The issue here is that both the length of each *x* vector and the total number of result vectors (*f* of *x*) to be multiplied (*N*) is very large, in the order of millions. Therefore, it is impossible to generate all the results at once (it wouldn't fit in memory) and then multiply them afterwards using `np.multiply.reduce` or the like .

A *toy example* of the type of code I would like to replace is:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.ones(1000000)
prod = f(x)
for i in range(2, 1000000):
    prod *= f(i * np.ones(1000000))
```

with `f` a vector-valued function with the dimension of its output equal to the dimension of its input.

To be sure: I'm not looking for equivalent code, but for a single, highly optimized function. Is there such a thing?

For those familiar with *Wolfram Mathematica*: It would be the equivalent to [Product](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Product.html). In *Mathematica*, I would be able to simply write `Product[f[i ConstantArray[1,1000000]],{i,1000000}]`.

Comment: You can't just do `np.prod(map(f, x))`?

Comment: Can you do `f(x)` where `x` is an array?  Or can `f` only work with a scalar value?  Your example, `np.sin(x)` works with an array input.  An alternative `math.sin(x)` only works with a scalar.

Comment: @chrisaycock, your `map` expression is Py2 only.

Comment: f is meant to take in a vector as input. For instance, f could be an fft (Fast Fourier Transform)

Comment: You mean like `np.prod(np.sin(np.arange(10)/5))`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yeah, I just saw that. It must be the same as in the second example. Corrected it now.

Comment: It sounds like the real question here is how to calculate `out[i, j] = f(x[i,:])[j]` or similar

Comment: Rewritten the question for clarity

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details about `f`? It's quite important to know how it handles multidimensional data. Does it allow an axis parameter like most numpy functions for example?

Comment: Let’s assume it’s fft.

Comment: Calculating the product is typically memory-bandwidth bound. The only thing to do is to speed up the calculation of f(x) as much as possible, or split the calculation of f(x) into chunks that fits into cache. Can you give a real world example of f(x)?

Answer (score 4):

Numpy [ufuncs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) all have a [`reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) method. [`np.multiply`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html#numpy.multiply) is a ufunc. So it's a one-liner:

```
np.multiply.reduce(v)
```

Where `v` is the vector of values you compute in what is hopefully an equally efficient manner.

To compute the vector, just apply your function to the input:

```
v = f(x)
```

So with your example:

```
np.multiply.reduce(np.sin(x))
```

**Alternative**

A simpler way to phrase the same thing is [`np.prod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html):

```
np.prod(v)
```

You can also use the [`prod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.prod.html) method directly on your vector:

```
v.prod()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. In my question f is not a vector but a *function* that *returns* a vector based on a calculation that depends on the index of the loop.

Comment: Does the function depend on the values in the loop or the index of the values?

Comment: The function is the same all the time, but of course yields different results for different inputs.

Comment: Except for a layer of function calling `np.prod` is `np.multiply.reduce`.

Comment: This works indeed for the example I gave (thanks for that), but I realize now that I have been a bit ambiguous. What if the xi's are not pre-calculated and present in a 2D array as in the question, but calculated on the fly based on *i*? I guess I'd better update my question or ask a new one, but I have to go now.

Comment: Update is fine since my answer is the only one and I don't mind. Normally, you'd ask a new question to avoid invalidating answers though

Comment: I updated the question to make it less ambiguous and to more clearly specify the problem (memory use).